# Http Client timeout when using DataFrame returned from Hive query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

This seems like a very odd and specific issue which has me stumped.

When using a `DataFrame` built by a `spark.sql("select * from table")` query on a Hive table, I get a timeout exception whenever I try to use an HTTP client in a transform or action step on that `DataFrame`.

Example:

```scala
import scalaj.http._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Example {

  def postDoc(doc: String): Unit = {
    val resp = Http("https://example.com/endpoint")
      .postData(doc)
      .header("content-type", "application/json")
      .asString
   }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.sql("select id, json_doc from some_table")
    df.map(r => r.getAs[String]("json_doc")).foreach(postDoc _)
  }
}
```

I can however hit the service through a `DataFrame` I create manually; i.e. `Seq((1, "{\"a\": 1}")).toDF("id", "json_doc").foreach(postDoc _)`.

I've also tried creating temp tables and using `spark.sql` to select from them; which works on a `DataFrame` that I create manually but not on ones sourced from a Hive table.

My partial `build.sbt`

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVersion =  "2.1.3"
  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
    "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.2"
  )
}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1950)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1945)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1514)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
        at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.scalaj$http$HttpRequest$$doConnection(Http.scala:367)
        at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.exec(Http.scala:343)
        at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.asString(Http.scala:492)
        at com.gm.avalanche.collect.Collector$.postDoc(Collector.scala:34)
        at com.gm.avalanche.collect.Collector$$anonfun$sqlTest$2.apply(Collector.scala:71)
        at com.gm.avalanche.collect.Collector$$anonfun$sqlTest$2.apply(Collector.scala:71)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1954)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1954)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:325)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.scalaj$http$HttpRequest$$doConnection(Http.scala:365)
        ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the socket was being closed remotely by the Ingress controller running in front of the Kubernates environment where the Elasticsearch instance is running. It was set to the default of a one minute timeout.